# Confusion regarding a Probability Question on a Knockout Tournament

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following is a part of an old STEP question.

> A tennis tournament is arranged for $2^n$ players. It is organised as a knockout tournament, so that only the winners in any given round proceed to the next round. Opponents in each round except the final are drawn at random, and in any match either player has a probability $\frac 12$ of winning. Two players are chosen at random before the start of the first round. Find the probability that they play each other in the first round.

The solution reads

> Call the two players $P_1$ and $P_2$. Once $P_1$ has been given a slot, there are $2^n −1$ slots for $P_2$, in only one of which will he or she play $P_1$.
> The probability of $P_1$ playing $P_2$ is therefore $\frac{1}{2^n -1}$.
> Note that this works for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$.

I don’t exactly get what they have done. To my understanding, the total number of pairings for the first round is $\binom{2^n}{2} $, only one of which will constitute the pair $P_1, P_2$. So, shouldn’t the probability be $$\frac{1}{\binom{2^n}{2}}= \frac{1}{2^{n-1} (2^n -1)}$$ ?

Comment: I expect the frustration here has to do with how we define a knockout tournament.  The phrasing of the question does a poor job of explaining it.  In a knockout tournament, generally, we will have all players playing simultaneously, just paired off into two person pairs.  It sounds like you read it as though the matches occur asynchronously.  Your answer is correct if the matches occur asynchronously or if you care about "which competition was shown on the spotlight" (*E.g. which game was aired on ESPN versus ESPN2 or ESPN4 etc...*).

Comment: In the interpretation used by the book's answer, we don't care which channel the game airs on, which stage it was on, which of the $2^{n-1}$ different "*first matches*" they happened to play in... just that they happened to play together in the first round wherever it happened to occur.  Your answer is then off by a factor of $2^{n-1}$ corresponding to the $2^{n-1}$ different locations they could have met for the first match.

Comment: Your working is based on two players being chosen out of $2^n$ players for a specific match.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah. So that’s what a ‘knockout’ tournament is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\binom{2^n}{2}}$ is the probability that a given match, say the first, is between players $P_1$ and $P_2$. Altogether, there are $2^{n-1}$ matches and so the overall probability is $\frac{2^{n-1}}{\binom{2^n}{2}} = \frac{1}{2^n -1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the 2 players are $P_{1},P_{2}$. If $P_{1}$ has been given a slot, then  the total slots  = Total - 1 = $(2^{n}-1)$ slots, which are available for  $P_{2}$ in only one of which $P_{2}$ will play $P_{1}$. Therefore, the probability of $P_{1}$ playing $P_{2}$ will be  $\frac{1}{\text{total Men -   oneSlotTakenByTheOtherMan} }$= $\frac{1}{2^{n} -1}$. Note that this works for $n=1$ and $n=2$.